# How can I redirect requests from the root context "/" to custom configured "server.context-path"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-oauth2

I have a simple Spring Boot web app which is configured with `@EnableAuthorizationServer`.
It is configured with `server.context-path=/uaa` and everything works as expected.

However, when I hit the app at the URL `http://localhost`, I get a 404.
I want to redirect those requests to `http://localhost/uaa`.

I tried creating a Filter but even though it is initialized it is never called.

I also tried overriding the `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` but is only seems to get called if I hit a 404 under the `/uaa` context.

**What is the correct way to achieve this redirection from `/` (`http://localhost/`) to `/uaa` (`http://localhost/uaa`)?**

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63269328/in-spring-boot-how-do-i-redirect-outside-of-the-context-path  It's a duplicate but with some answers

Answer (score -4):

Set `server.context-path=/uaa` in the application.properties.

Comment: this is not an answer to the question. OP is asking about redirecting not how to set a custom context-path.