# In spring boot, how do I redirect outside of the context-path?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I have a spring boot application, in the properties file I have defined:

```
server.servlet.context-path= /myapp
```

If I go to `http://localhost/myapp` I see everything as expected. However if I go to: `http://localhost` I see a standard 404 error page from Apache Tomcat.

How can I setup a redirect from `/` to `/myapp` in spring boot?

Alternatively / equivalently: Can I setup multiple context-paths in a single spring-boot application?

Comment: Why don't you just create `@Controller` mapped to the `/` root, which redirects to your context-path?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri - context-path trumps the path specified by a controller's `@RequestMapping`, so if I the controller to `/` it prefixes that with the context path and binds to `/myapp/`.

Comment: @Matthew even if the absolute path is provided?

Comment: If you are using Tomcat as the servlet engine you can probably use a rewrite rule to forward requests from / to the target path. Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493444/spring-boot-tomcat-rewritevalve

Comment: You mean when you launch the application, it should open `localhost:port/myapp` ?.

Answer (score 5):

Your question will result in bad referenced app later because you are arrived on a webname and you are landing everytime on a redirect... Bad way to go.
If I were you, I will put the things correctly at the start : create a root virtualhost inside your Tomcat and serve your application with root "/" context, and not "/myapp", unless you (or your client, boss) want it like that...

**Example config from a VirtualHost with Apache Tomcat :**
From https://tecadmin.net/create-virtualhost-in-tomcat/

```
<Host name="example.com"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
 <Alias>www.example.com</Alias>
 
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="example_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t %r %s %b" />
 
 <Context path="" docBase="/opt/tomcat/webapps/myapp1" debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
</Host>

<Host name="mydomain.org"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
 <Alias>www.mydomain.org</Alias>
 
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="mydomain_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t %r %s %b" />
 
 <Context path="" docBase="/opt/tomcat/webapps/myapp2"
    debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
</Host>
```

Comment: The confusing thing for me is that I am 'just' a Spring Boot user, not a tomcat user. I understand that tomcat is there, but ideally it's not something I want to care about. Is there a Spring Boot way of having multiple contexts in a single app? (I'm guessing the answer is "no")

Comment: Of course there is a way to define multiple contexts inside your Spring application. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54308472/multi-context-spring-boot-application-how-to-define-standard-spring-boot-proper
or https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-context-hierarchy

Comment: You can look at that GitHub.com repository too https://github.com/kulabun/spring-boot-multi-context

Comment: OK - I tried multiple contexts, and it works. But they share a global context-path. Can you point me to an example where there are two contexts with different context paths?

Comment: You can imagine the same configuration for Tomcat I have provided in my answer, inside the same Tomcat VirtualHost and not in twice `<Host ...>`. The interesting parts are `<Context path="/context1" docBase="/opt/tomcat/webapps/myapp1" debug="0" reloadable="true"/>` and another one with `<Context path="/context2" docBase="/opt/tomcat/webapps/myapp2" debug="0" reloadable="true"/>`

Comment: If you are trying to define multiple root contexts, then it will not work properly : one tomcat context is one application which can handle multiple subcontexts ie with your spring application. It could work with some hacking, but it will be a mess to manage in a daily working workflow. You must define a servlet which handles a specify path in your app 1 and another servlet which handles another specific path in your app 2 and define them inside your tomcat / wildfly root context path, and then it is the same than defining multiple sub contexts for one web app. And it is the simplest one.

Answer (score 2):

If you package SpringBoot application as `jar`, Tomcat would be included as the default embedded container.

You can't ask the embedded Tomcat to host multi web-app like what it could do as a standalone service.

So we have two choice:

1. Run a reverse proxy in front of your SpringBoot application. Such as [Nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)
2. Package your SpringBoot application as a `war`, and put it into some container.

   For example:

   1. Download tomcat and start it with default configuration.
   2. Build a `my-app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war`, rename it to `myapp.war` and copy it to your tomcat's `/webapps` directory.
   3. You can visit `http://localhost:8080/myapp`, tomcat could host all valid folders and wars in `/webapps`.

PS: If you are using `Spring Reactive Web`(WebFlux, Netty), the second method wouldn't work.

**UPDATE**

Here is what I said about `ServletRegistrationBean` in comments.

```java
  // use DispatcherServlet here
  private ServletRegistrationBean<? extends Servlet> createServletRegistrationBean(
      ApplicationContext context, String name, String... urlMappings) {
    final DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet();
    dispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(context);

    final ServletRegistrationBean<DispatcherServlet> servletRegistrationBean =
        new ServletRegistrationBean<>(dispatcherServlet, urlMappings);
    servletRegistrationBean.setName(name);
    return servletRegistrationBean;
  }

  @Bean
  public ServletRegistrationBean<? extends Servlet> oneContextPath(ApplicationContext context) {
    // create applicationContext or use the auto configured one
    return createServletRegistrationBean(context, "firstOne", "/*");
  }
  @Bean
  public ServletRegistrationBean<? extends Servlet> anotherContextPath(ApplicationContext context) {
    return createServletRegistrationBean(context, "secondOne", "/myapp/*");
  }
```

As this example, we can run `http GET /foo` and `http GET /myapp/foo` at the same time.

Notes:

1. WebFlux is **NOT** supported.
2. Custom applicationContext if you need.

Comment: If you use Maven, you can specify inside the `<build>` section, a `<finalName>myapp.war</finalName>`.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to understand is *why* does embedded tomcat only support a single application / context? But I'm willing to accept that it's one-of-those-things.

Comment: A good question. After some search, I find that I'm wrong. We can't set multi context in  properties, but we can do it by: custom and register multi `ServletRegistrationBean` for every  web context you want.

Comment: How do you figure this stuff out? Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: The multiple `ServletRegistrationBean`s works - but it's on top of the path - so the resulting URL is `/context-path/myapp/<whatever>`. It's a solution to the problem, but using a different mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You have so many options to do that and for external servers by WebServerFactoryCustomizer

```
@Bean
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory>
  webServerFactoryCustomizer() {
    return factory -> factory.setContextPath("/context");
}
```

With Spring Boot 1, we can create an instance of EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer
  embeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
    return container -> container.setContextPath("/yourContext");
}
```

Or with java System property

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("server.servlet.context-path", "/yourContext");
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

Comment: These allow me to change the context-path - but they don't allow me to have multiple contexts paths active.

Comment: @Matthew, I don't think that you can achieve this in static way, you will need to have dynamic context path configuration to have more than. I think [this link should help you](https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/blog/configuring-a-dynamic-context-path-in-spring-boot)

Comment: I did see that link - it doesn't really make the context path dynamic. What it does is simulate a context path using wrapping / filtering. Though I appreciate this is a subtle distinction - and that what I'm looking for might not be possible!